# Using PDO::FETCH_CLASS with Magic Methods

Tags: php, pdo, magic-methods

I have a class that uses magic methods to store properties.  Here is a simplified example:

```
class Foo {
    protected $props;

    public function __construct(array $props = array()) {
        $this->props = $props;
    }

    public function __get($prop) {
        return $this->props[$prop];
    }

    public function __set($prop, $val) {
        $this->props[$prop] = $val;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to instantiate objects of this class for each database row of a `PDOStatement` after it's executed, like this (doesn't work):

```
$st->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Foo');

foreach ($st as $row) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

The problem is that `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` does not seem to trigger the magic `__set()` method on my class when it's setting property values.

*How can I accomplish the desired effect using PDO?*

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP PDO: Fetching data as objects - properties assigned BEFORE __construct is called. Is this correct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862279/php-pdo-fetching-data-as-objects-properties-assigned-before-construct-is-ca)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default behavior of PDO is to set the properties before invoking the constructor. Include `PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE` in the bitmask when you set the fetch mode to set the properties after invoking the constructor, which will cause the `__set` magic method to be called on undefined properties.

```
$st->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'Foo');
```

Alternatively, create an instance and fetch into it (i.e. set fetch mode to `PDO::FETCH_INTO`).

Comment: Thank you, this works.  Out of curiosity, is there a performance benefit to setting them before invoking the constructor?  I don't understand why `PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE` wouldn't be the default behavior...

Comment: @drrcknlsn: for as much of a "why?" as there is, see the other question. Note that comments aren't meant for additional questions beyond requests for clarification.

Comment: I did read the link you pasted, but there is no answer for why this is the default behavior.  I'm asking this in the comments because it's not significant enough to warrant opening a new question, IMO, but I still want to know.

Comment: @drrcknlsn: the other question has as much of an answer as there is.