# PHP Inserting DB values into values in a class

Tags: php, mysql, class, mysqli

I want to pull values from the DB and insert them into variables in a class.

IS the best and ideal way to just create a DB class and then reference that class within the main class to set the protected values to the values from the DB?

```
    if(!empty($S)){
        $_client_id=$S['API_ID'];
        $_client_secret=$S['API_PASSWORD'];
        $_client_id=$S['API_SECRET'];
        $_access_token=$S['API_TOKEN'];
        $_username=$S['API_USER'];
    }

class MyClass
{
    protected $_client_id = '20123123';
    protected $_client_secret = '76fesresg45grgerg3g34';
    protected $_username = 'letsHe'
```

Comment: This question is missing information, what database handler are you using? PDO, MySQLi? If PDO, look at [PDO::FETCH_CLASS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898794/using-pdofetch-class-with-magic-methods)

Comment: MySQLi did not know that database handler was important in this case.

Comment: You should be handling this using a dependency injection model.  That would be the proper way, if that's what you're looking for.  A good write up on that with some basics to get you started can be found here: http://php-di.org/doc/understanding-di.html

Comment: Then the function would be [mysqli_result::fetch_object](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use [PDO's ability to manipulate objects.](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/objects)

Get rid of mysqli, and use PDO to get your objects right out of SQL:

```
class MyClass
{
    protected $client_id;
    protected $client_secret;
    protected $username
}

$sql = "SELECT * from my_class where id=1";
$myClassInstance = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchObject('MyClass');

$sql = "SELECT * from my_class";
$myClassCollection = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'MyClass');
```

Note that unlike mysqli, PDO can let you provide constructor parameters, call setters, assign properties either before or after constructor call.

Comment: And as var names are different from column names `SELECT API_ID as client_id` etc...

Comment: @AbraCadaver for this case you may define a magic __set() method that will do the appropriate modifications.

Comment: I think you refer to the method `fetchObject()`, since `fetchClass()` does not exist.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, the last line must be ´fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'MyClass');` or it will not work.

Comment: @PhilippPalmtag damn me again you are right. I should think of the answer I am writing, not the job task at hand