# Is there a reason why PDO does not have option to create objects via constructor with FETCH_CLASS?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

It seems like there is no way to make PDO create the new object using constructor/setters when using PDO::FETCH_CLASS.

Currently with FETCH_CLASS the member variables get filled using reflection I guess. They are certainly not passed through constructor. That's a pitty because it circumvents any checks you may have in your constructor to ensure object's consistency (task cannot have $status = finished while not having $finishedDate set).

There are various options, some of which are special to very edge cases (like PDO::FETCH_NAMED). That leads me to the assumption that constructor creation is not implemented because there is some reason why it's not a good idea.

**Note:** I am not looking for the third argument of fetchAll (ctor_args) that does not pass the row's values, but rather the supplied ones.

**Update:** It seems I was not clear in describing what I'm asking. Imagine I have constructor like this:

```
public function __construct($id, $number) {
    if ($id == $number) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Number and ID can't be same");
    }
}
```

and do

```
SELECT id, number FROM table
```

With any settings, even `$st->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'Foo');` it won't throw an exception and will happily create the object in inconsistent state. Because the values are not set via constructor. Actually closest approximation of what I would call expected behaviour would be what's mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33027392/112000

**Update:** I created a feature request for this https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73397 just in case you're interested in it as well.

Comment: I think this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898794/using-pdofetch-class-with-magic-methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's for historical reasons.

At first there was `mysql_fetch_object` - just to supplement the fetching triad - a list, a hash, an object - to create a class instance right off the database row.

Then enter PDO, with a lot of nice features, but still under the same paradigm - to assign the newly created variable's properties after the columns in the database.

So I think that it's simply because nobody had an idea that PDO can be used this way.

So I think that the nearest outcome you can get [using a closure to create an instance](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_FUNC):

```
$job = $pdo
    ->query('SELECT id, number FROM users')
    ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_FUNC, function($id,$number) {return new Job($id,$number);});
```

Comment: So this is what I wrote exactly. You just have to use properties instead of variables. Is it a such a big problem for you?

Comment: Yes, that is currently the only possible way to do it. My original question is **WHY isn't there PDO::FETCH_CLASS_CONSTRUCTOR or something** when there are other (much less used) ways to fetch.

Comment: Because PDO implements some magic that helps to avoid some unnecessary coding. While you don't need that magic. So there is no reason to use PDO features.

Comment: BTW, why don't you like the first method? You have a ready made class structure and trying to marry it with PDO?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126758/discussion-between-tomas-fejfar-and-your-common-sense).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to call the constructor before populating your objects. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php#98876):

> if you want to fetch your result into a class (by using PDO::FETCH_CLASS) and want the constructor to be executed *before* PDO assings the object properties, you need to use the PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE constant:

```
<?php
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("your query");

$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, "className", $constructorArguments);

# pass parameters, if required by the query
$stmt->execute($parameters);

foreach ($stmt as $row)
{
    // do something with (each of) your object
}
?>
```