# How can I fetch correct datatypes from MySQL with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

my PDO fetch returns everything as a string.

I have a user class with id (int) and username (varchar).

When I try the following sql request

```
$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=:id_user');
$db->bindParam(':id_user', $id_user);
$db->execute();
$user_data = $db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and var_dump($user_data), the id parameter is a string. How can I make it so PDO respects the correct datatypes from mysql ?

Comment: You're going to struggle with that in php. I suggest you cast in php what you are expecting.

Comment: Do you mean after each request I should intval() / strval() each parameter manually ?

Comment: yeah, I usually do 'echo (int) "1";' or echo (string) "1";

Comment: Is this really an issue in the first place? Are you having problems because the result is not an int?

Comment: Yes, I have issues with it when encoding the result to JSON and using booleans in my front-end.

Comment: @Ping just as a side note: MySQL' boolean is actually a tinyint synonym. So explicit typecasting is your friend when dealing with MySQL to JSON via PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a different *[fetch_style](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)*. If you have a *User* class, you could force PDO to return a instance of the *User* class with

```
$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "User");
```

You can now take care of properties validations and casting inside the *User* class, where it belongs.

Related:

- [PHP PDO: Fetching data as objects - properties assigned BEFORE __construct is called. Is this correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862279/php-pdo-fetching-data-as-objects-properties-assigned-before-construct-is-ca)
- [PDO PHP Fetch Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137051/pdo-php-fetch-class)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is an excellent idea that will result in cleaner code.